# Apache: filtering proxied content

Tags: apache, filter, proxy, apache2, mod-proxy

I'm trying to configure my local Apache intallation as a (forward) proxy, and modifying the content before it is send to the client application. My configuration file - inspired by "Apache Cookbook: Solutions and Examples for Apache Administration", Section 10.7 ([link](http://books.google.ie/books?id=RJhfgczxKvUC&lpg=PA209&ots=iqcaoUNkP6&dq=apache%20setoutputfilter%20proxy%20sed&pg=PA209#v=onepage&q=apache%20setoutputfilter%20proxy%20sed&f=false)) - looks as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:8344>
  ProxyRequests On
  ExtFilterDefine fixtext mode=output intype=text/html cmd="/bin/sed s/and/AND/g"
  <Proxy *>
    SetOutputFilter fixtext
  </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

The proxying itself seems to work. When I configure my browser to use the the proxy (127.0.0.1:8344) and start Apache, browsing works (and it's not working when Apache is not running). However, the filter seems to be ignored completely. Nothing in error.log or access.log indicates any problem. I guess I'm missing somehting here. Any hints are much appreciated!

Comment: This question sounds relevant to what you want to achieve: http://serverfault.com/questions/222823/phpapache-as-forward-reverse-proxy-how-to-process-client-requests-and-server

Comment: rmeakins, thanks for the link! You're right, it's pretty close to my problem. And in a sense I comply with the reply since I got a first running setup using the Privoxy proxy server. Although, it's that Apache would be more powerful since it seems to possible to run external scripts (e.g.. Perl scripts) over the content (instead of the simple SED command).